# Max-width and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

I fear this is a stupid newbee question but i didn't find any info on it (here or elsewhere): how to implement the max-width instruction for `IE`? I have read extensively about the bugs when max-width is applied to pictures, but, to my desperation, nothing about plain text.
In my stylesheet I have:

```
P {max-width: 600px}
```

and `Firefox` and `Chrome` duely limit the length of a line of text to `600p`x but `IE` (v. 8 to 10) does not. (I verified this on different computers.)
What am I doing wrong? Can max-width not be applied to a paragraph in `IE`?

Comment: Where is the code you're talking about?  Show a concise example that duplicates the problem.  Have you tried adding a `width`?

Comment: better you read this link.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530811(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
p.paragraph {
    display: block;         /* just to be sure - it's not needed */ 
    max-width: 600px;       /* for most modern browsers (not IE < 8) */
    width: auto !important; /* IE max-width hack */
    width: 600px;           /* width value for IE */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you may find surprising is that max-width is actually working.  If you use the F12 developer tools, and select the element, you will see that it's with is indeed 600px (assuming you have filled it with something larger than 600px).

The problem is most likely that your content is overflowing the element.  If you want it to clip, then you should set `overflow:hidden`, or perhaps `overflow:auto` to see a scrollbar.

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nSJw9/

You can also set `word-wrap:break-word` if you want it to wrap unbreakable text, although technically css3 changed the name to overflow-wrap, word-wrap is considered an "alternate name" because it's been supported for so long.

http://jsfiddle.net/XuF33/1/

FYI, Chrome does exactly the same thing as IE here, so I'm not sure why you claim it works with Chrome but not IE.  Maybe you need to include your HTML

Answer (score -1):

Putting width on the paragraph itself might not be the best practice, put a div around it. IE 8 is said not to support max-width as long as initial width is not set.

Comment: There is nothing wrong (or bad practice) about setting a `width` on a `p` and enclosing it within a `div` should not be required.